# QGIS RGB image to HSL (Hue Saturation Luminance)

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator, raster-conversion

is it possible using QGIS (2.10) on windows to convert an RGB image file to HSL (Hue Saturation Luminance) format.

I've seen various formulas for this written in Java however they only seem to be for converting single values. I am looking to convert whole images.

I also have access to ArcView 10 + spatial analysis and Global Mapper 16.2.

Comment: in QGIS use Grass7 tools to go from RGB to HIS http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/i.rgb.his.html  see example here http://planet.qgis.org/planet/tag/landsat/ (terminology HIS & HLS are the same)

Comment: This looks like it would be perfect. I've only used Grass a few times and i'm running into problems simply opening my raster. i'm setting my EPSG code to 27700 - OSGB36 > import raster data > Common formats import > Geotiff and it appears to import fine until i try to zoom to the extent i get error "unable to zoom to raster map <#>" and <#> not found.

Comment: solved that issue seems grass can only open single band geotiffs so i split my image into R G & B bands using arcGIS. i don't think this tool is quite what i'm after as it seems to be backwards (compared to its name) seem to generate RGB values from a hue input.